# How can I inherit a magic static singleton?

Tags: c++11, singleton, static-methods

I would like to inherit from a magic static singleton in a derived:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main();

class SingletonBase{
protected:
    int i=0;
    SingletonBase(int){}
    //
    friend int main();
    static void show(){
        static SingletonBase s(2); // this is sometimes referred to as the "magic static singleton pattern"
        s.i++;
        std::cout << "SingletonBase::i="<<s.i<<"\n";
    }
};

class Singleton: public SingletonBase{
private:
    Singleton(int):SingletonBase(int{}){}
    int j=0; // unfortunately, Singleton has data, too.
public:
    static void show(){
        static Singleton s(3);
        s.i++;
        s.j++;
        std::cout << "Singleton::SingletonBase::i="<<s.i<<". Singleton::j="<<s.j<<"\n";
    }
    //
};

int main() {
    Singleton::show();
    Singleton::show();
    Singleton::show();
    Singleton::show();
    SingletonBase::show();
    SingletonBase::show();
    SingletonBase::show();
    Singleton::show();
    Singleton::show();
    Singleton::show();
    Singleton::show();
}
```

The output is:

```
Singleton::SingletonBase::i=1. Singleton::j=1
Singleton::SingletonBase::i=2. Singleton::j=2
Singleton::SingletonBase::i=3. Singleton::j=3
Singleton::SingletonBase::i=4. Singleton::j=4
SingletonBase::i=1
SingletonBase::i=2
SingletonBase::i=3
Singleton::SingletonBase::i=5. Singleton::j=5
Singleton::SingletonBase::i=6. Singleton::j=6
Singleton::SingletonBase::i=7. Singleton::j=7
Singleton::SingletonBase::i=8. Singleton::j=8
```

But what I expected (and need) is for `i` to increase by `1` in each output line. That is, *the* Singleton (there is supposed to be only one) shall inherit *the* SingletonBase.

How can this be done?

### Remark

I cannot unfriend main.

The application context is that I have two distinct types `template<typename T>ElementA` and `template<typename T>ElementB` with much mutual functionality. So I inherit both from a `template<typename T>ElementBase`. Both are putting stuff on a `StackA<T>` and `StackB<T>`, respectively, that share a lot functionality in turn. So I inherit both stacks from `StackBase<T>`. In the above example, `main` is the `ElementBase` calling upon `SingletonBase`; and `SingletonBase` in turn is `StackBase`, since being the base of `Singleton`, which models `StackA / StackB`.

Unfriending `main` means `ElementBase<T>` cannot push into `StackBase<T>`, meaning I'd have to implement everything for A and B redundantly.

Comment: _"That is, the Singleton (there is supposed to be only one) shall inherit the SingletonBase"_ - But you've created two instances (one `SingletonBase` and one `Singleton`), so why do you expect there to be only one?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Speaking of cities, I would expect there exits one Manhatten (SingletonBase) and one New York (Singleton).

Comment: Well, New York _isn't a_ Manhattan, is it? Why the inheritance? They can both reference a separate (singleton) instance if you want.

Comment: @TedLyngmo. Sure. I get you. But here I need it to be in a context like "if Manhatten builds 1000 homes then also New York has +1000 homes" .

Comment: This could be controlled by a governing class. Don't mix what doesn't belong together.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Ugly.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main();

class SingletonBase{
private:
    int i=0;
    SingletonBase(int){}
    //
    friend int main();
    friend class Singleton;
protected:
    static SingletonBase& Instance(){
        static SingletonBase s(int{});
        return s;
    }
    static void show(){
        std::cout << "SingletonBase::i="<< Instance().i++ << "\n";
    }
};

class Singleton{
private:
    Singleton(int){}
    SingletonBase* b;
public:
    //
    static Singleton& Instance(){
        static Singleton s(int{});
        s.b = &SingletonBase::Instance();
        return s;
    }
    static void show(){
        std::cout << "Singleton.SingletonBase->i="<< Instance().b->i++ << "\n";
    }
    //
};

int main() {
    SingletonBase::Instance().show();
    SingletonBase::Instance().show();
    Singleton::Instance().show();
    SingletonBase::Instance().show();
    Singleton::Instance().show();
    SingletonBase::Instance().show();
}
```

So the idea is to compose a static state of Singleton and its Base by use of a pointer to the base instead of inheriting it. Because the interface to the outside from both singletons is channelled through the `Instance()` function, the only risk remaining is with memory leaks within the implementation of Singleton (e.g. overwriting `b`).